# SyntaxError when implementing While Loop

Tags: python, while-loop, syntax-error

**Background** -
I am trying to implement logic in a function which keeps looping through 'Code Block #1' whilst it's true (`while True "meta" not in api_response:`), with a 60-second break between loops.
If the Code Block #2 is true (`except "meta" in api_response:"`) then I want to return `api_response`, ready to be called by another function.

**Function** -

```
def unpack_response():
    api_response = api_call()
# Code Block # 1    
     while True "meta" not in api_response:
        meta_value = "meta"
        res = [val[meta_value] for key, val in response.items() if meta_value in val]
        meta_value = "".join(res)
        percent_value = "percent_complete"
        res = [val[percent_value] for key, val in response.items() if percent_value in val]
        percent_value = "".join(res)
        print(f' Your data requested, associaed with ID: {meta_value} is {percent_field} complete!')
        time.sleep(60)
            continue
# Code Block# 2
     except "meta" in api_response:
        return api_response
     break
```

**The issue** - currently, I seem to be getting the following `SyntaxError`:

```
  File "<ipython-input-212-0757814896ea>", line 3
    while True "meta" not in api_response:
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Remove the misplaced `True`. Where is the `try` corresponding to the `except`? Also, `continue` is indented incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code is edited as per your code and requirement, have added break with 5 iterations as there was no proper break available in your condition.
The syntax error you were getting is because, you need add some boolean operands in between as **or**, **and**.

```py
def unpack_response():
    count=0
    api_response = api_call()
# Code Block # 1    
     while "meta" not in api_response:#no need of true
        count++
        meta_value = "meta"
        res = [val[meta_value] for key, val in response.items() if meta_value in val]
        meta_value = "".join(res)
        percent_value = "percent_complete"
        res = [val[percent_value] for key, val in response.items() if percent_value in val]
        percent_value = "".join(res)
        print(f' Your data requested, associaed with ID: {meta_value} is {percent_field} complete!')
        if "meta" in api_response:
            return api_response
        if count==5:
            break
        time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: @william can you upvote the answer as well if it answers your query